# Couldn't display body field on a view with Search Api

Tags: views, search

I have a view that I set it up with Search Api and Facet Api, I couldn't display the body field of indexed nodes.

I tried to add it to the Search Api index fields but it still the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 solutions to add body field:

- **Solution 1:**

  1. Browse to search api index field configuration at `/admin/config/search/search_api/index/hone_and_strop/fields`
  2. Now add **The main body text** field from **Add related fields** list.
  3. Now do reindexing and you would be able to add body field into view.
- **Solution 2:**

  1. Create view mode with body field in it.
  2. Now in view, use **Rendered entity** instead of fields.

> Note: You always need to do reindexing whenever you add or remove
>   field form search api index field configuration.

Comment: I already done that, is there any other setting to apply?

Comment: Try using Rendered entity instead of fields in view.

Comment: That's worked with rendred entity even if if it is not the better solution. Thank you

Comment: OK. I have updated my answer. Kept previous solution so that any other user get to know.